# Validation error of type UndefinedFragment: Undefined fragment

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I've a `graphql-jave v8.0` app running on `Spring boot v1.5.10`, and I'm trying to utilize '[fragment](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments)' feature of GraphQL to fetch limited number of fields with the following schema type definition:

```
type School {
   id: ID
   name: String
   address: String 
   age: String
   jobTitle: String 
   ...
}

fragment UserFields on School {
   age
   jobTitle
}

type Query {
  user (id: String!): School!
}

schema {
  query: Query
}
```

When I execute this query:

```
{
   user (id: "123")
   {
     ... UserFields 
   }
}
```

The expected result should be:

```
{
  "user": {
     "age": "12",
     "jobTitle": "student"
  }
}
```

However, It results in the following error

```
    "message": "Validation error of type UndefinedFragment: Undefined fragment 
     UserFields @ 'user'",
```

Off course I can do this with explicitly passing the field name in the query but for the sake of example, I'm interested in utilizing `fragment` feature of GraphQL.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

Fragments aren't defined in the schema, they're something for letting you create abstractions whilst building complex queries -- the main purpose is to allow you to avoid repetition when querying the same type in multiple parts of your query.

Answer (score 0):

As [Andrew said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49957650/294657), and as the [official docs exemplify](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments), fragments are not defined in the schema but (ad hoc) in the query:

```
{
   user (id: "123") {
     ... UserFields 
   }
}

fragment UserFields on School {
   age
   jobTitle
}
```

Unconditional fragments (like the one here) are used to avoid repetition. Imagine having multiple places where you want to select `age` and `jobTitle` in the same operation.

Conditional fragments, on the other hand, are used to make a conditional selection depending on the concrete interface implementation or union subtype.